# How to catch response of server in mitmproxy container and past it into file in json format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

I need to catch and fill in separated file every response,request which is going through my mitmproxy container.

## Dockerfile

```
FROM mitmproxy/mitmproxy:latest

RUN mkdir url_catching
WORKDIR /home/$USER/url_catching
COPY ./url.py .



EXPOSE 8080:8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mitmdump","-s","./url.py"]
```

## Docker run

```sh
sudo docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 mitmdump_url:latest
```

## My pyhton script(sry, i am novice in python)

```py
from mitmproxy import http

def response(flow):
    url_request: str = str(flow.request.pretty_url)
    url_request = url_request.replace("/", "_")
    with open(url_request, "ab") as ofile:
        ofile.write(flow.request.pretty_url.encode())
        ofile.write(flow.request.content)
        ofile.write(flow.response.content)
```

- in the result i get separated files for each request and name of it is equal to url of request, but only url is in human readable format everything else is encoded or just missed.
  So i need to past response which is going through my proxy in json format to files.

Comment: I tested it with https://httpbin.org/get which sends JSON data in response and I get JSON in file. What url did you used?

Comment: my nginx server on another instance

Comment: what do you get in web browser when you access nginx? What do you see directly in mitmproxy? I tested with other options on httpbin.org - ie. compression gzip, brotli, deflate - and I always get correct data in file and in mitmproxy. maybe test your code with https://httpbin.org

Comment: i get my php app in browser. while testing your site  i get in mitmproxy console ``` << Cannot establish TLS with client (sni: httpbin.org): TlsException("SSL handshake error: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert certificate unknown')],)",)
my_ip:64572: clientdisconnect
my_ip:64568: GET https://httpbin.org/static/favicon.ico
                << 200 OK 21.86k
my_ip:64568: GET https://httpbin.org/static/favicon.ico
                << 200 OK 21.86k``` but in the file is only html code i didn't get the request headers

Comment: but you don't save headers in your code - so you can't get headers in file - you save only content which means body/HTML

Comment: ok, my bad, i need the headers or request

Comment: `content` means `body`.  `request/response` has `headers` + `empty line` + `body/content`

Comment: see `flow.requests.headers` and `flow.response.headers`

Comment: thanks, btw do u know how to avoid static content?

Comment: web browser loads automatically `favicon.ico`, images, css, javascript. I tested it with module `requests` so I loaded only HTML without any other elements.

Comment: you can also filter elements in your code and skip elements which have `/static/` in url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request/responde` has `headers` + `empty line` + `body/content`

I show two methods to convert `headers` to `string`/`bytes`.

As normal lines of text

```
for key, value in flow.response.headers.items():
    ofile.write('{}: {}\n'.format(key, value).encode())
```

Result

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 14 Jan 2020 11:51:49 GMT
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Server: nginx
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 181
Connection: keep-alive
```

As JSON. I convert to `dict()` because headers can't be directly converted to `JSON`

```
d = dict(flow.request.headers.items())
d = json.dumps(d, indents=2)
ofile.write(d.encode() + b'\n')
```

Result

```
{
  "Host": "httpbin.org",
  "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.22.0",
  "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
  "Accept": "*/*",
  "Connection": "keep-alive"
}
```

I also skip urls with '/static/'

```
from mitmproxy import http
import json

def response(flow):
    url_request: str = str(flow.request.pretty_url)

    if '/static/' not in url_request:
        url_request = url_request.replace("/", "_")
        with open(url_request + '.txt', "ab") as ofile:

            ofile.write(b'--- url ---\n')
            ofile.write(flow.request.pretty_url.encode() + b'\n')

            ofile.write(b'--- request ---\n')

            ofile.write(b'--- headers ---\n')
            #for key, value in flow.request.headers.items():
            #    ofile.write('{}: {}\n'.format(key, value).encode())
            d = dict(flow.request.headers.items())
            d = json.dumps(d, indents=2)
            ofile.write(d.encode() + b'\n')


            ofile.write(b'--- content ---\n')
            ofile.write(flow.request.content + b'\n')

            ofile.write(b'--- response ---\n')

            ofile.write(b'--- headers ---\n')
            for key, value in flow.response.headers.items():
                ofile.write('{}: {}\n'.format(key, value).encode())

            ofile.write(b'--- content ---\n')
            ofile.write(flow.response.content + b'\n')
```

To put all as one JSON you would have to first create dictionary with all elements (headers, body, etc.) and next use `json.dumps(all_elements)`

---

Testing code

```
import requests

proxy = {
    'http': 'http://localhost:8080',
    'https': 'http://localhost:8080',
}

urls = [
    'https://httpbin.org/get',
    'https://httpbin.org/gzip',
    'https://httpbin.org/brotli',
    'https://httpbin.org/deflate',
    'https://httpbin.org/encoding/utf8',
]

for url in urls:
    print(url)
    r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy, verify=False)
    print(r.text)
```

One of file with results

```
--- url ---
https://httpbin.org/get
--- request ---
--- headers ---
{
  "Host": "httpbin.org",
  "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.22.0",
  "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
  "Accept": "*/*",
  "Connection": "keep-alive"
}
--- content ---

--- response ---
--- headers ---
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 14 Jan 2020 12:06:04 GMT
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Server: nginx
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 181
Connection: keep-alive
--- content ---
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.22.0"
  }, 
  "origin": "83.23.66.224, 83.23.66.224", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

Comment: avoid static content means to avoid js,png,html, etc

Comment: in Python's web frameworks "static" means mostly elements from folder `/static/` like files `.js`, `.css`, images but `HTML` is dynamically generated so it is not treated as "static"`. You can skip  files `.js`, `.css` and  images in similar way as I  used `if '/static/' not in url_request:`. But if you want to skip `body` from all contents then you have to skip `flow.response.content`

Comment: i don't have to even create the file if there is "static content"

Comment: like in my oode - `if '/static/' not in url_request:` skip some urls and it doesn't create files for them.